# using find function and make the resulting cell as selection in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Hope you are enjoying good health.

I have a data recording file to keep record of POs and than it payments. I was using excel file with lots of different formulas to maximize the automation of operations. But it is getting heavier and it is impossible to work with it any more.

So I generated the idea to remove all the formulas and put it in first row only. Now i want excel to copy those formulas from that first row every time i run the command and past at the required row to update the records and immediately should it convert into value. This will keep all the data updated with automation and reduction in processing time.

The script i am using here is working but at one point i have to use find function. it should find the required value in column B of selected sheet and make selection of cell found as results. After the selection it will offset to a desired column to proceed the further steps.

```
Sub find()
Sample Sheets("PO").Range("a1"), Sheets("PO").Range("b:b")
End Sub
```

The complete script is

```
Sub Macro4()
'
' Update the PO/WO detail with the effect of new payment entry and alsoupdate the corresponding in payment entry
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+j
'
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -16).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "*"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Previous.Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    End Sub
    Sub find()
    Sample Sheets("PO").Range("a1"), Sheets("PO").Range("b:b")
    End Sub

    Sub Sample(FirstRange As Range, ListRange As Range)
        Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range, oRange As Range

        Set oRange = ListRange.find(what:=FirstRange.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)


        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Range("A1").Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Range("A1").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "*"
        Selection.End(xlUp).Select
        Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Range("A1:B1").Select
        ActiveCell.Activate
        Selection.Copy
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Range("A1").Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -10).Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Range("A1").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.ClearContents
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -10).Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Next.Select
        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 16).Range("A1:B1").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 16).Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -16).Range("A1").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.ClearContents
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 17).Range("A1").Select
    End Sub
```

Kindly suggest any resolution,

Thanks in advance

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emm, if I understand your problem correctly, all you need is a select statement.

```
    Set oRange = ListRange.find(what:=FirstRange.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    oRange.Select
```

Although you don't use your oRange variable anywhere else in your code, so you might just get rid of it. Did you write this code? Do you understand it? This is by no means a clean, optimized, good, readable or fast code... But if it works for you, then never mind that.

Comment: I can understand the script to some extent but not every part. I recorded the procedure and mold it to my requirement and some part are used form others work.